# How to use setInterval to get a number every second?

Tags: javascript

I want to ask a question. My English is not very good, but I try to describe my problem~ I am

practicing using setInterval. The problem is that there is a range of numbers from 1 to 10. Use setInterval to collect one number every second until all 10 numbers are collected. Stop capturing!

Because I'm still a beginner, I don't know how to implement it, so please help me here, thank you.

```js
let demo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  setInterval(function(){
    //Don't know how to write here
  },1000);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `collect a number every second`? What do you want to do to the number on each interval?

Comment: Sorry I didn't describe the problem clearly. My problem is that I want to use setInterval to fetch a number from the array every second, from 1 to 10 to the 10th, and then stop fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code.

```
let demo = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log(demo.shift());
    if(demo.length == 0) clearInterval(interval);
},1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and iterate the array. While iteration use the index to print the value at the regular interval. Also note index starts from 0. At same time assign the setInterval to a variable and clear the interval after regular interval. Also you could have used setTimeout instead of setInterval

```js
let demo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function logVal(arr) {
  arr.forEach((item, index) => {
    let interVal = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(item)
    }, (index + 1) * 1000);

    setTimeout(() => {
      clearInterval(interVal)
    }, (index + 1) * 1000)
  })

}

logVal(demo)
```